# How to convert date to the Brazilian standard using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-ee-7

I'm having problem to convert the xml object using JAXB. The date is in the format `Sun Jan 30 16:08:23 BRT 18`, but need to convert to the Brazilian format `12-08-2009 16:08:23`.

The input is coming in format `2009-08-12 16:08:23` and want output `12-08-2009 16:08:23`.

Conversion class JAXB:

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    Locale brasil = new Locale("pt", "BR");
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", brasil);

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.format(v);
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception, ParseException {
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }
}
```

Where i call the Adapter.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
private Date ultima_atualizacaoProduto;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same `DateFormat` both both parsing as well as formatting. Assuming `30` is the Year in your question, here is how you can do it:

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private Locale brasil = new Locale("pt", "BR");
    private final SimpleDateFormat SD1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private final SimpleDateFormat SD2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        return SD2.format(v);
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception, ParseException {
        return SD1.parse(v);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
2009-08-12 16:08:23
```

Output:

```
12-08-2009 16:08:23
```

Comment: Not worked. Continues output Sun Jan 30 16:08:23 BRT 18. The output is comming 2009-08-12 16:08:23. I edited the ask.

Comment: You should mention the input/output format clearly in the question. Updated the solution! Try now...

Comment: Output Sun Jul 01 07:20:01 BRT 2012.

Comment: Thanks, your solution practically solved my problema;. In hour of output, i just used SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");                      System.out.println("Atualização Produto: " + sdf.format(produto.getUltima_atualizacaoProduto()));

Comment: I tried to choose your answer as the best, but I'm still not sufficient reputation. Sorry!

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer. You need reputation to up-vote. You have to click on the greyed-out right tick just below the voting counter.

Answer (score 0):

in general only use UTC time for DB and transfer and convert it with java8 java.time.*.

If JDK<8, you can use joda time api.

Comment: I am using JDK 8.0.72.

Comment: Good, then use java.time api.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/20-examples-of-date-and-time-api-from-Java8.html